# PDF export on macOS Mojave does not show axes correctly

Tags: plotting, legending, pdf-format

I am using Mathematica 11.3.0.0 on macOS 10.14.3. I found something goes crazy when I exported a plot with legends. In the notebook, everything seems fine

[image]

Then I used the export command to export it as a pdf. It becomes something like

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

P.S. Here is the code

```
PTest2 = LogLogPlot[{Tanh[x], x}, {x, 10^-3, 10^3}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"tanh(x)", "x"}]];
Export["plot_test_2.pdf", PTest2];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  Please edit your post by clicking the gray `edit` button at the bottom of your post, and include typed-in *Mathematica* code, properly formatted in code blocks, instead of screen-shots. Also include all relevant code (including the `Export` command you used). This helps us help you.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on `11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)` Mac OS version Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: Also unable to reproduce on `11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)` Mojave 10.14.2. If you are on 10.14.3, are you in the macOS beta program? Is it possible it's a problem with the beta?

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the issue with version 11.3 on macOS **10.14.3** (which is not in beta status btw.).

Comment: Thanks guys! Although I am still not sure about the cause, I have reset my Mathematica to its default and the problem is solved.